# How to display a position of a vector like this?

Tags: symbols

How to display a smile symbol like this? For example, the `k_2`th place is `a_1`.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use `\overset` and `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\place}[2]{%
  \overset{\substack{#1\\\smile}}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
(\place{1}{a_{1}},a_{2},\dots,\place{k_{2}}{a_{1}},
 a_{2},\dots,\place{k_{3}}{a_{2}},
 a_{3},\dots,\place{k_{r+1}}{a_{r}},
 b_{m+1},\dots,b_{n})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]